# UIWebview contenteditable crash in UITextSelection caretRect

Tags: ios, uiwebview, contenteditable, user-interaction

I have a UIWebview which the user can edit (iOS 6 and above).  The webView has userInteractionEnabled YES, and the HTML has contenteditable TRUE, as follows:

```
- (void)configureView // called from viewDidLoad and setDetailItem:
{
    NSString *htmlString = @""
    "<html>"
    "<body>"
    "<div contenteditable=\"true\">"
    "1: Click on this line (keyboard appears)<p>"
    "<textarea>2: Clicking in this textarea causes crash</textarea><p>"
    "</div>"
    "</body>"
    "</html>";

    [myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

    myWebView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Clicking in the line of text brings up the keyboard.  Then, clicking in the textarea causes a crash somewhere in Apple's code:

> -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 2204

and this console output (courtesy of NSZombieEnabled):

> *** -[UITextSelection caretRect]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x746ae90

What am I doing wrong?

(Other info: I'm loading the UIWebView in a brand new Universal project using storyboard and ARC.  The crash happens on the iPhone/iPad Simulator and my iPhone 3GS 6.1.3.)

Comment: Why do you want a textarea inside a `contenteditable` element?

Comment: For the application I have in mind, the text won't normally be edited, but the textareas will be.  Anyway, even with contenteditable set to false, there is no change in the behavior.

Comment: Correction: setting contenteditable to false prevents the kybd form appearing when clicking on the text, so the problem does not appear.  But, I'd like to be able to select or edit the text outside of the textareas.

Comment: hi Jeff, i also face this problem with document.execCommand("InsertHTML", false, '<input type="Text" value="nicks"/>'), i think the problem is in contenteditable="true" textarea not editable. if found any solution then plz share

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an Apple bug -- I field a bug report and they said it was a duplicate.  Here's a workaround: put the straight HTML text(s) and the textarea(s) inside separate div tags.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same problem of "UIWebview contenteditable crash in
UITextSelection caretRect". and i got solution.
Solution:-Textarea has bydefault property of contenteditable=true so we don't need to add in   please add below code
`example:-
"<div contenteditable=\"true\">"
"1: Click on this line (keyboard appears)<p>""</div>"
<div> "<textarea>2: Clicking in this textarea causes crash</textarea><p>"</div>`
It is working for me :-)